# SQL datareader reading inconsistently

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I have the following code in C#-

```
private void sendnotificationmail(string enqid)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        List<string> maillist = new List<string>();
        string sql = "SELECT     TrussLog.repmail, TrussLog.branchemail, TrussEnquiry.DesignerEmail FROM         TrussLog FULL OUTER JOIN                      TrussEnquiry ON TrussLog.enquirynum = TrussEnquiry.Enquiry_ID         where TrussEnquiry.Enquiry_ID = '" + enqid + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[0].ToString()))
            {
                maillist.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[1].ToString()))
            {
                maillist.Add(reader[1].ToString());
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[2].ToString()))
            {
                maillist.Add(reader[2].ToString());
            }
        }
        connection.Close();

        if (result != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            processmail(maillist);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

I am getting the value of the variable enqid from a combobox on my Windows form.The contents of the combobox are retrieved from the database. On form load, the combobox displays the first enquiryID retrieved from the database. When I run my program the data reader skips the loop. However if I select a different enquiry in the combobox, the data reader works properly

Comment: It could be that the first `enquiryId` yields no results. You're current code is exposed to SQL Injection. Use a parameterized query instead.

Comment: the first enquiryID is retrieved from the database

Comment: Is it retrieved using the same query?

Comment: Why is there an empty catch? Remove it and retest.

Comment: A SQL injection vulnerability and an empty catch block.  That should make for pretty much impossible debugging outside the IDE...

Comment: @David and not forgetting the connection is only closed if there is no error: `using` block missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've forgot to *associate* `Command` with the `Connection`:

```
  // SendNotificationMail is more readable then sendnotificationmail
  private void sendnotificationmail(string enqid) {
    // put IDisposable into using...
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere")) {
      con.Open();

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
        cmd.Connection = con; // <- You've omitted this

        // have SQL readable
        cmd.CommandText =
          @"SELECT TrussLog.repmail, 
                   TrussLog.branchemail, 
                   TrussEnquiry.DesignerEmail 
              FROM TrussLog FULL OUTER JOIN                      
                   TrussEnquiry ON TrussLog.enquirynum = TrussEnquiry.Enquiry_ID         
             WHERE TrussEnquiry.Enquiry_ID = @prm_Id";

        // use parametrized queries
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Id", enqid);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (reader.Read()) {
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And *never*, *never after* write code alike

```
  catch (Exception)
  {
  }
```

which means "just ignore *all the errors* and continue".

Comment: And the catch swallowed the error. Why do people think that suppressing errors fixes them?! Never understood that.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, you are right about that he isn't defining the connection to the command.